# Endless horizontally scrolling view to draw content dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create the following view / set of views which behave following way:

1. I have huge set of points which have been stored to DB in web server.
2. My client application downloads those and should draw curved lines about the data.
3. What components should I use here to get this "infinite" scrolling view to draw content dynamically.
4. No snapping wanted, so it should be smooth and can stop to every X position.

Should I proceed with this by using HorizontalScrollView with horizontal LinearLayout and remove/add views based on scrolling, then translate the scrolling position and provide fling that the scrolling doesn't stop suddenly.

Or is just one canvas possible to use and draw the content to simulate the scrolling?

Maybe a horizontally scrolling ListView component?

The solution should be efficient and use minimum of memory.
Which solution do you recommend, or do you have some new ideas other than above?

All suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Picture to demonstrate the component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several possibilities:

Create custom `View` class and implement `GestureDetector` there. You can get movement of finger, calculate currently visible area and draw only visible part of content.

May be this solution is not the easiest to implement, but it will be fast and does not require   any resources.

Comment: Are there any differences in performance when using View versus SurfaceView?

Comment: SurfaceView usually used when you have to draw heavy images (for example it used in camera preview). If you have simple image it is easier to use plain View

Comment: The answer you posted seems to be pretty straight forward, do you have any other ideas or do you personally recommend this one? Do you think fast scrolling can draw smoothly this way?

Comment: I use this way for creating "pinch-to-zoom" image view, and there was not any problems with performance - drawing is faster than finger movement. If you have not spend much time for data processing - use this way.